# What is the meaning of "the ship reached the line"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "the line" mean in "the ship reached the line" in the Rime of the Ancient Mariner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's one of the significant lines of latitude: the equator, or Tropic of Cancer or Capricorn.

Comment: This would benefit from supporting citations (from analysis of the poem and explanation of named lines of latitude).

Answer (score 3):

Reaching, crossing or passing the line refers to a ship **passing over the equator**. Among many examples of the usage I offer:

> [Forces](https://www.forces.net/news/crossing-line-navys-rite-passage-gain-acceptance-king-neptune)
> Crossing the Line' is one of the oldest traditions in the Royal Navy and takes place when a ship crosses the equator.
>
> Royal Navy tradition dictates that any ship crossing the equator must pay its respects to the Lord of the Seas, King Neptune, to gain his acceptance.

“The Line” may thus be understood as the line traced on the Earth’s surface by the equator.